# Make more planets orbit

Tags: html, css, animation

How do I make more planets spin arround my sun? I have a sun in the middle, an earth spinning arround it and I want to spin mercurius arround it aswell in the right lane obviously, so between the sun and earth. The problem is that I don't know why it's not creating it's own orbit. I am following a tutorial from learntocode but it's leaving me to finish it, though I find it truly hard. On my website it doesn't rotate but in my fiddle it does? What?

https://jsfiddle.net/4rdyg8tj/

http://planets.lucavanraalte.com/

Html:

```
<body>
<!-- Right below is an image of the sun -->
<img id="sun" src="http://i.imgur.com/C8lLjeM.png">

<!-- Insert the 'earth' on the next line -->
<div id='earth-orbit'>
<img id="earth" src="http://i.imgur.com/XeueGf6.png">
 </div>

<div id='mercurius-orbit'>
<img id="mercurius" src="http://i.imgur.com/06XMdvX.png">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
html, body {
/* The universe takes up all available space */
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

/* The universe is black */
background-color: black;
}

#sun {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;

height: 200px;
width: 200px;
margin-top: -60px;
margin-left: -60px;

border-color: orange;
border-width: 8px;
border-style: solid;
border-radius: 50%;

box-shadow: 0 0 128px red;
}

#earth {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50%;

height: 50px;
width: 50px;
margin-left: -25px;
margin-top: -25px;
}

#mercurius {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50%;

height: 50px;
width: 50px;
margin-left: -25px;
margin-top: -25px;
}

#earth-orbit {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;

width: 600px;
height: 600px;
margin-top: -250px;
margin-left: -250px;

border-width: 2px;
border-style: dotted;
border-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;

-webkit-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
-ms-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
-o-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
}

#mercurius-orbit {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;

width: 400px;
height: 400px;
margin-top: -250px;
margin-left: -250px;

border-width: 2px;
border-style: dotted;
border-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;

-webkit-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
-ms-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
-o-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes spin-right {
100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}

@keyframes spin-right {
100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}
```

Comment: It rotates on your page too.

Comment: Now it does, i fixed it

Comment: "Eppur si muove!" - Galileo Galilei

Answer (score 1):

**Edited** with different positions of planets

```css
html, body {
    /* The universe takes up all available space */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    /* The universe is black */
    background-color: black;
}

#sun {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: -60px;
    margin-left: -60px;

    border-color: orange;
    border-width: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 50%;

    box-shadow: 0 0 128px red;
}

#earth {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;

    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-top: -25px;
}

#mercurius {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40%;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    right: 96%;
}

#earth-orbit {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: -250px;
    margin-left: -250px;

    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: dotted;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;

    -webkit-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
    animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
}

#mercurius-orbit {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: -150px;
    margin-left: -150px;

    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: dotted;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;

    -webkit-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
    animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes spin-right {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spin-right {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<!-- Right below is an image of the sun -->
<img id="sun" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/sun-earth-code/sun.png">

<!-- Insert the 'earth' on the next line -->
<div id='earth-orbit'>
    <img id="earth" src="http://i.imgur.com/XeueGf6.png">
</div>

<div id='mercurius-orbit'>
    <img id="mercurius" src="http://i.imgur.com/06XMdvX.png">
</div>s


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you know how I could start them seperately?